# License compatibility for proprietary software

Tags: license-compatibility, proprietary-code

I'm making a software project that I will make as a proprietary software, which I will make a business model by providing service support to recipients or customers. In making target software, apart from using my own software/source code, I also plan to combine it with source code licensed under open source software licenses such as Apache 2.0, MIT, BSD 3 Clause and MPL 2.0 to complete the target software that I will be create, Is such a proprietary software model possible?, or only some (if not all) licenses allow to be combined?

Then do I have to state the original author or contributor of any source code that I use in the proprietary software that I will produce?, even if I do not modify the source code.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can do it, but it's hard to give an answer for all combinations; when you copy open source into your product, you have to consider each software license's requirements separately. I would recommend you first simplify your problem to the combination My Proprietary Software + Apache 2.0, and see how to satisfy the requirements of the license. Then consider My Proprietary Software + MPL and do the same. Afterwards, fulfilling  MIT and BSD-3 clause conditions as well would be trivial.

Comment: And of course you can just grab all the software, claim it is your work without crediting any of the authors. Just like anyone could do with your software. Regardless of licenses. Joke aside: Yes, of course, you will have to fullfill the license obligations of *every single work you use* - and each requires at least giving appropriate credit - or you become liable to license violation claims. Details of your obligations are usually outlined in the licenses and copyright statements.

Comment: My advice: **Read all of the licenses,** and figure out whether your proposal will comply with them. If some aspect of those licenses is confusing to you, you can ask another, more specific question about that individual issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well Apache MIT and bsd are permissive so all they will require is copy right and license notice as well as stating changes to the Apache code simply by adding a notice. But your not required to disclose source for those files, now Mozilla license does require you to disclose the files that were used or modified to remain under the MPL but the binary could be under a different license. If you do modify the MPL files you need only disclose the files not the library or the binary.